# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lusb-1.0 when try to make install

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cmake, gnu-make

I was trying to compile an example app from ZED2 camera, but when I execute `make` after `cmake ..` It throws me error as follows:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so', needed by 'ZED_Depth_Sensing'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ZED_Depth_Sensing.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ZED_Depth_Sensing.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

then I made the symlink :

```
libusb-1.0.so -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0
libusb-1.0.so.0 -> /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0
```

and try to `make` again, this time it throws me this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so when searching for -lusb-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so when searching for -lusb-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so when searching for -lusb-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lusb-1.0
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/ZED_Depth_Sensing.dir/build.make:131: recipe for target 'ZED_Depth_Sensing' failed
make[2]: *** [ZED_Depth_Sensing] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ZED_Depth_Sensing.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ZED_Depth_Sensing.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Smells like you are building the project for **32**-bit but your `libusb-1.0` library is **64**-bit. Or vice versa. Creating under the directory `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/` a symlink pointed to a library in `/lib/i386-linux-gnu` is definitely wrong: From directories' names you could guess that `x86_64-linux-gnu` is for 64-bit things but `i386-linux-gnu` is for 32-bit ones.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I rm the link and relink it from `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsub.so.0.1` and it works, though another problem occured